# How to force/understand CSS specificity?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate a website (angular.io), and thus its CSS. However, the CSS specificity isn't working correctly.

The height property is the one in question. In their website, the height property is taking the value of the less specific. However, in mine, it's applying the most specific. This is the HTML & CSS:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container"></mat-sidenav-container>

mat-sidenav-container.sidenav-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto!important;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

.sidenav-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Click See image of their website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuaXV.png)

Comment: .sidenav-container will always has a height value of 100vh. So document height.

Comment: the default value of height is auto, not 100vh

Comment: Yes, I misread the code. Can you write which result you want to get please? 100vh height?

Comment: Your observation is incorrect. The value in that website is `height: auto !important`, the more specific one as expected.

Comment: @ariferol01 yes I would like 100vh as a final result without changing the code

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava height: auto is more specific, yes, but it's not being applied in their website. 100vh is being applied there. However, in mine, it's the opposite

Comment: Can you post any evidence supporting this claim? Last I checked, it was applying the `height: auto !important` style like it should.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I updated the question to include an image of the problem as requested

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows that the more specific styles have been commented out / unchecked manually, most probably by yourself.

Comment: You disabled the style with devtools by unticking it

Comment: Thank you guys! Kindly post an answer so i can upvote/mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

If you add CSS `.sidenav-container { height: 100vh!important; }` to direct class name, the property value take the all elements have this class.

If you want to use only specific elements, you can add important to only specific elements: `mat-sidenav-container.sidenav-container { height: 100vh!important; }`

- Sorry for mybad English :)